# Unable to login all registered users using userdefaults in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, nsuserdefaults

In my code I am unable to login all registered users, I am only able to login the last registered  user. Here loginVC is retrieving last registered user. How to save all registered user details in userdefaults to login all users?

In `loginVC`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "USER_LOGIN") {
                //navigate to home page
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                }
            }

}
@IBAction func loginBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
 
    let uName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName")
    let uPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userPassword")
    if userNameTextfield.text == uName && passwordTextfield.text == uPassword{
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "USER_LOGIN")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
         navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    else{
        showAlert(title: "LogIn", message: "please enter username and password")
    }
}
```

**in registeredVC:**

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!
@IBAction func registerBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if firstNameTextfield.text?.isEmpty == true{
        self.showAlert(title: "Registration", message: "please enter first name")

    }
    else if lastNameTextfield.text?.isEmpty == true{
        self.showAlert(title: "Registration", message: "please enter last name")

    }else if emailTextfield.text?.isEmpty == true{
        self.showAlert(title: "Registration", message: "please enter email")

    }else if passwordTextfield.text?.isEmpty == true{
        self.showAlert(title: "Registration", message: "please enter password")

    }
    else{
        
        let fName = firstNameTextfield.text!
        let lName = lastNameTextfield.text!
        let userNameReg =  fName + " " + lName
        
                UserDefaults.standard.set(userNameReg, forKey: "userName")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(lastNameTextfield.text, forKey: "lastName")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(emailTextfield.text, forKey: "email")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(passwordTextfield.text, forKey: "userPassword")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "USER_LOGIN")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
         navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)        }
}
}
```

How to auto login all registered users, please do help with code.

Comment: Please note that storing passwords in UserDefaults is a massive security breach. You should use a secure solution instead.

Comment: @EricAya, sure i will KeychainWrapper instead UserDefaults, but there also same issue

Comment: Your mistake here is tied to your usage of UserDefaults (you're overwriting values, among other issues). So no, you won't have the same issue if you trash that code and start anew with proper usage of Keychain.

Comment: you are over-riding the old data... you should store arraylist instead...

Comment: @FahimParkar could you pls guide me to store data in array using userdefaults

Comment: @FahimParkar if i try like this `KeychainWrapper.standard.set([passwordTextfield.text], forKey: "userPassword")` then in login page i am getting nil in `uName  and uPassword` any suggestions

Comment: Edit your question to show your new Keychain based code, along with the results you are getting. My guess is that you are trying to cast the values you get from your keychain to String type with a conditional cast (`as?` and the type doesn't match because you are saving an array now.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code for saving usernames and passwords is flawed on several levels, and should be rewritten.

1. Don't store secure info like usernames and passwords to user defaults. That is a HUGE security hole, as pointed out by Eric Aya.
2. You are saving the current username and password using the same key every time. Your code is written to save the current user, not an array of users/passwords. IF you want to retain an array of users/passwords, you have to save an array of users/passwords. (set up your code to maintain an array of users/passwords. Read the **array of** current values from your secure store.. When the user enters a new username, add it to your array and re-save that array to your secure store.

Comment: could you pls guide me to store data in array using userdefaults

Comment: Just use `UserDefaults.set(_:forKey:) and pass in an Array of String objects instead of a single string. But you **SHOULD NOT BE SAVING SECURE INFO LIKE USERNAMES AND PASSWORDS TO USERDEFAULTS, FULL STOP!**

Comment: if i try like this `KeychainWrapper.standard.set([passwordTextfield.text], forKey: "userPassword")` then in login page i am getting nil in `uName  and uPassword`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is setting as below.

```
KeychainWrapper.standard.set([passwordTextfield.text], forKey: "userPassword")
```

This way what you are doing is ***always setting new array list of current password*** only which is erasing old data. (which is wrong)

Below is what you can do

**Step 1 : First get the array list of data you have stored.**

```
var currentArrayList = KeychainWrapper.standard.get(forKey: "RegisteredUsers")
```

E.x array list is as below.

```
[
  {
    "username": "user01",
    "password": "123456"
  },
  {
    "username": "user02",
    "password": "123456"
  }
]
```

**Step 2 : When register, add this user object in the above array list.**

Now if you enter new user, you will append that user in the array list.

```
currentArrayList.append(newUserObject)
```

**Step 3 : Save this arraylist back to Keychain***

```
KeychainWrapper.standard.set(currentArrayList, forKey: "RegisteredUsers")
```

Note : You must save the whole user object and not just username & password separately.

Comment: here what is `newUserObject`